# Ruby - Install Sinatra gem error on ruby mine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm working on a new project in Ruby, which I'm learning, and I need to install Sinatra gem and I'm getting the following error:

> "Following gems were not installed: sinatra-sinatra (0.10.1):  While
>   executing gem ... (Gem::UnsatisfiableDependencyError)
>        Unable to resolve dependency: 'sinatra-sinatra (= 0.10.1)' requires 'rack (>= 1.0)'"

Currently I'm using, RubyMine (Windows). Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not RubyMine, but some other dependency conflict in your app. The gem `sinatra-sinatra` requires Rack 1.0, there is probably another gem in your Gemfile that requires a greater or different version of the same gem.

Actually, I believe your problem can easily be fixed by using the proper gem. [`sinatra-sinatra`](http://rubygems.org/gems/sinatra-sinatra) is a very old gem, if you want to use the `Sinatra` framework the correct gem is [`sinatra`](http://rubygems.org/gems/sinatra). Update your `Gemfile` accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

In you machine

```
gem install sinatra-sinatra
```

Check you `Gemfile`

```
gem 'sinatra-sinatra', '~> 0.10.1'
```

Delete the `Gemfile.lock` and bundle its once again.